# FileNotFoundException is occur while running Wpf application on 32bit machine

Tags: c#, wpf

I created setup file using Inno setup.I have exe,dll and one xml file in my setup.

When I install on 64 bit machine it works fine means it take xml file from directory where exe is present.

But When I install same setup on 32 bit machine it take dll path but while accessing xml file it takes path of desktop where shortcut of exe is present and showing FileNotFoundException.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the exception happening while the program is running or during installation?

Comment: During running application

Comment: I found where is problem.Windows XP 32Bit machine take path of Document And Setting to get documents for application while running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get path of working directory of application while loading xml file in code.

```js
string WorkingDir=System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

XDocument temp_xdocument= XDocument.Load(WorkingDir+"file.xml");
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is most likely not specifying pathnames on the files it is trying to open, so it is expecting to find them in the current directory. Inno Setup by default does not set the "Start In" field on shortcuts its creates; this causes Windows to pick a directory itself, which usually won't be the directory containing your application.

In virtually all cases, this is something that should be corrected at the application level. Properly designed GUI applications should not expect to be started from a particular directory; they should always specify full pathnames on files they open. In Delphi or C++Builder, for example, it's possible to get the full pathname of the directory containing the application EXE by calling: ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)). To get the full path of a file named "File.txt" in the application directory, use: ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'File.txt'.